# Firing ListGrid selection item on GWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

When the user clicks a button, I want to fire the ListGrid Selection event. I called "resultControl.resultGrid.selectRecord(0);"  but it didn't work.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me. Can you please provide some details & code(if possible) about it?

Comment: when the user click a button i want firing the event   resultGrid.addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEvent event) {
   System.err.println("here my code");
      }
  });

Comment: in others words i want simulate a click on a ListGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your initial question and your comment, I understand that you want to simulate a selection event in your ListGrid, through a button. Assuming that I understand well, and you are only interested in one record selection (the first one), all you have to do is the following:

```
    final ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();
    //Initialize your listgrid's data etc.

    listGrid.addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEvent event) {
            SC.say("here my code");
        }
    });


    IButton button = new IButton("Select");
    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            listGrid.selectRecord(0);

        }
    });
```

A last note, System.out or System.err won't produce anything when your application runs in production mode. Use a suitable logging solution or the SC.say(), if you want to provide the user with a message, instead.